# Can't debug Chrome Extensions (v3) using external source maps? Unsupported protocol scheme chrome-extension:// [Updated w Partial Fix]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I can get them to load inline, but when I change my builder to use external stylesheets, I keep getting this error.

I've tried recommendations mentioned in other SO posts, but they all seem to be related to v2 and haven't helped me.

Specifically adding this to the manifest: (retyped on mobile quickly)

```
{
 "web_accessible_resources": [{
   "resources": ["*.js.map"],
   "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"]
 }]
}
```

> Could not read source map for chrome-extension://ooodmkmklcjkca
> opcpffalcikkebdmdo/src/content-scripts/highlighter/app.js: Unexpected
> 503 response from
> chrome-extension://ooodmkmklcjkcaopcpffalcikkebdmdo/src/content-scripts/highlighter/app.js.map:
> Unsupported protocol " chrome-extension:

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDdoh.png)

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj1mC.png)

[Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie5HE.png)

Comment: As the error says, it's not implemented. You'll have to use inline maps, e.g. `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` in webpack.

Comment: I don't think that's the final answer, I think that's the quick fix; which I've already implemented via Vite/Svelte.

I think it's simply a new setting that's not well documented, or a bug that's been reintroduced with Manifest v3. There are other threads showing Chromium implemented a fix for this in v2 via Chrome Canary 29, but that recommended setup is no longer working. Opening an issue with Chromium to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Digging into this while in a meeting for the greater good of humanity.

It looks like I got it working externally without generating the errors, but only when I'm looking at the debugger inside of Chrome DevTools. Inside of Visual Studio Code, it takes me to the minified version every time I step in the chrome debugger.

Ideally, this should take me to the exact [svelte] file and let me step through and edit that single file; like every other script I've ever debugged. With the inline debugger, it opens up a cloned read-only version of my [.svelte] file, which forces me to check the variables there and then go to the writeable file to make edits; which I've never had to do in any other language.

Anyways, this looks like a very common question when it comes to debugging Chrome Extensions, so I hope it helps some people and I hope someone can improve on this. If I figure out the other issues, then I'll update this answer with my changes.

`manifest.json`

```json
//Specific to this repo
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "src/popups/app.html"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "src/side-panels/app.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["src/content-scripts/highlighter/app.js"]
    }
  ],
  //Manifest v2 Recommended change
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["*.js.map"],
        "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
             //This config is meant for content_scripts, so this is just a random domain. Would probably be nice if it could go to options.html, popup.html, etc. automatically for debugging. Not sure how to get that working though.
            "url": "https://www.svelte.dev/",
            //Opens chrome and injects the unpacked extension and auto opens dev tools to trigger debugging automatically
            "runtimeArgs": ["--load-extension=${workspaceFolder}/dist", "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"],
            //Stops the errors imaged above
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        },
        { 
            //Requires Debugger for Firefox Extension
            "type": "firefox",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Firefox",
            "url": "https://svelte.dev/", 
            "addonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/dist"
        }
    ]
}
```

`vite.config.js`

```js
...
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    emptyOutDir: true,
    sourcemap: true
  },
  ...
});
```